# When generating a debug APK, I encountered an error. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When generating a debug APK, I encountered an error. How can I resolve this issue?

"react-native": "0.72.5",
"@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^7.5.0",

```
Task :@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:extractDebugAnnotations FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:extractDebugAnnotations' (type 'ExtractAnnotations').
Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\91950\Desktop\mobile app\albia_app\node_modules@react-native-camera-roll\camera-roll\android\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out'.

Reason: Task ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:extractDebugAnnotations' uses this output of task ':react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:compileDebugAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to upgrade camera-roll library version. use below command

npm install @react-native-camera-roll@latest

Answer (score -1):

1- Sometimes, Gradle cache can cause unexpected issues. Try cleaning the Gradle cache by running the following command in your project directory:
./gradlew clean
2- check path, ':@react-native-camera-roll_camera-roll:extractDebugAnnotations, does it exist